# Find the bigger number in a file

Tags: c++, graph

So, my problem is: I have a .txt file, and inside I have 3 columns of numbers, with a space between each other, something like this:

> 1 1 1
>   2 2 2
>   3 3 3
>   4 4 4
>   .  .  .

I need to open this file, go through each line and find the bigger number between the TWO first columns of numbers. In this case, I'm trying to find the bigger vertex to know the size of my graph. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sorry, but SO is not a code writing service. What did you try till now?

Comment: Well, I tried to create pointers to each column and temporarily store the values using strtok to stop at the spaces, but I can't make it work.

Comment: Read the numbers, then compare them. For more specific answers ask more specific question. If you have problems with the code you wrote so far, reduce it to a [mcve] and post it along with the actual and desired behavior as well as a clear problem statement.

Comment: See also: [results of searching for C++ read file column](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+read+file+column&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: See also: [StackOverflow c++ read file space separated](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+read+file+column&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+read+file+space+separated)

Comment: Specifically, what is your confusion:  reading column numbers?  Finding the largest number?  (Edit your question with the answers.)

Answer (score -2):

I didn't compile it so you should probably slightly adjust it:

```
FILE* f = fopen("file.txt", "r");
int a, b, c, biggest = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
while(fscanf(f, "%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c) != EOF){
  int max_of_two = max(a, b); // maybe you need this result ?
  biggest = max( biggest, max_of_two );
}
printf("%d\n", biggest );
```

Comment: Downvoted: 1. This is poor because code only answer without explanation. 2. Even if the code was correct, it is poorly written and 3. the check in the loop is nonsense.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Not to mention that it's almost a C answer (save for the `std::numeric_limits`), whereas the question is tagged [tag:c++].